# Chart.js with line chart and bar chart - bar chart not rendered although the max value of it is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am using chart js (https://www.chartjs.org/) and I have a line chart and I want to add a bar chart to it as a second dataset. The problem is the line chart displays but the bar chart doesn't however, the max value of the bar chart dataset is shown. What I mean is, the line chart max value is 1, and the bar chart max value is 2 and the chart displays goes up to the value of 2.

If I remove the line chart dataset then the bar chart is successfully drawn but when they are put together only the line chart is displayed. It does add the label to the legend though its just not displaying the bar.

Below is my chart object

```
activeUserChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: result.data.chart_labels,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Total Daily Active Users',
                        data: result.data.chart_data.active_user_data,
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(209, 0, 21, 0.2)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(209, 0, 21,1)'
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'bar',
                        label: 'App Analysis',
                        data: result.data.chart_data.app_release_data,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero:true,
                                //stepSize: 1,
                                autoSkip: true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
```

What's wrong with my javascript object that it won't render the bars on the chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it, for some reason I had to swap the main type to be bar and then override the type in the dataset to be line as below:

```
activeUserChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: result.data.chart_labels,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                        type: "line",
                        label: 'Total Daily Active Users',
                        data: result.data.chart_data.active_user_data,
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(209, 0, 21, 0.2)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(209, 0, 21,1)'
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    },
                        {
                            label: 'App Analysis',
                            data: result.data.chart_data.app_release_data,
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
                            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
                            borderWidth: 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero:true,
                                //stepSize: 1,
                                autoSkip: true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
```